# MySQL : selecting data based on a timestamp interval

Tags: mysql

My dataset is a table with 3 rows : ID of a hard-drive, percentage of empty space, timestamp. The table is appended with the new state of each HDD (1200 of them) every 20 minutes.

If I want to pick the last state of my HDD pool, I go for a MAX(timestamp), and a MIN(timestamp) if I want the oldest.

But say I have a given timestamp, how can I ask MySQL to retrieve data from more or less X seconds around this timestamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE yourTimeStamp 
  between TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,-3,yourtimestamp) 
      and TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 3,yourtimestamp)
```

where -3 and + 3 was substituted for X

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd for more help.

Comment: it works ! but it is very slow. Any idea on how to speed this task up ?

Comment: I'd need to see the joins There might be a way to calculate the timestampadd ONCE and use it for every record instead of Each record.  I'd also have to see how you're getting the "MAX" and a few other things.  The SQL you're using along with Execution plan would help determine where the bottleneck is and what to do to resolve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB('<given_timestamp>', INTERVAL 5 SECOND) 
    AND DATE_ADD('<given_timestamp>', INTERVAL 5 SECOND);
```

As mentioned in the other answer, your query is slow when selection is based on the `timestamp` field.

You can add an `INDEX` on that column to speed it up:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD INDEX(`timestamp`)
```

Note that, depending on the size of your table, the first time you add an index it takes a while. Secondly, it slows down `INSERT` queries and adds to the size of your database. This is different for everybody so you just have to find out by testing.

Comment: @Cystack sorry, you're right. fixed that ... btw, to speed up queries based on your timetstamp field you have to add an index on that column

Comment: it is already indexed, it just takes around 16 seconds, which I think is quite long :/ your code works now though ;) and is as fast (or as slow) as the other ! thanks

Comment: @Cystack glad it works ... you can run `EXPLAIN <your query>` to find out why it executes so slowly